# In Amazon API use ItemSearch with respect to category only

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-advertising-api

I am using Amazon Product Advertising API, I want to retrieve all products of a category. What I want to know is can I **only provide a category** without passing any Keyword into the ItemSearch operation and retrieve the complete set of product records including their sub-category products.

I tried passing this parameter in an array without supplying a 'Keyword' item:

```
$category = 'Software';    
$single = array(
      "Operation"     => "ItemSearch",
      "SearchIndex"   => $category,
      "Condition"     => "All",
      "ResponseGroup" => "Medium,Reviews"       
    );
```

But it does not work. Please help me.

Let me explain again in short that all I want is to get the complete list of Products by passing any category **without passing any Keyword**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would probably want to perform a `BrowseNodeLookup`.  This operation will let you iteratively navigate up and down the tree of ancestors/children based on the passed Browse Node ID.

Here is the documentation for that operation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BrowseNodeLookup.html

The list of top level Browse Node ID's is here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BrowseNodeIDs.html

You could then use the Browse Node Id that you are interested in and pass that in to the ItemSearch as a parameter value.  You would not need to include the keyword parameter at all in this case.

Operation might look like:

```
$browse_node_id = '409488'; // browse node id for Software in US or other browse node determined by using BrowseNodeLoookup   
$single = array(
  "Operation"     => "ItemSearch",
  "BrowseNode"    => $browse_node_id,
  "SearchIndex"   => "All", // we don't need to limit to certain category here as browse node does this
  "Condition"     => "All",
  "ResponseGroup" => "Medium,Reviews"       
);
```

Comment: First of All really thanks for your reply! 
Please tell me two things:
1.) That what BrowseNodeLookup returns? It returns only sub-category or child category names or it returns the products contain under sub-categories?
2.) And can we pass multiple Browse Node Id in this Operation?

Comment: I have updated my answer to be more specific about how you would use BrowseNodeLookup in conjunction with ItemSearch. Sorry if it was unclear before.  You cannot pass multiple Browse Node Id's to my knowledge.  You would need a separate request for each.

Comment: @Noman The BroseNodeLookup itself will return you any Browse Nodes that are children to the input node as well as the full ancestory of the node all teh way to its root browse node.  You can think of this like navigating through a directory structure. You would only use this request to find a browse node id you are interested in and then use this browse node id as a parameter in ItemSearch.

Comment: THANKS A LOT!
Now Please let me repeat what I understand.

I have to pass an Id in BrowseNodeLookup operation, it will return me ancestors and childs of that ID. Then I will apply another operation of itemSearch, and pass the result id (anyone) in that operation and then I dont't need to pass any Keyword parameter. Am I right Mike ?

Comment: Yes.  The BrowseNodeLookup just gives you a means of navigating to a specific category or subcategory.  Once you find the browse node ID for the category/subcategory you are interested in, you can pass that browse node id into ItemSearch as search parameter. See updated answer for example of the search that should work for you.

Comment: Okay! Now everything really got clear. Thanks is really a small word for the help you did. Bundle of Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, got involved in some other Project. The Operation 'BrowseNodeLookup' works really perfect. But Operation ItemSearch (code you pasted above) is not working, just returning array but not returning any values of that browsenodeid.

Comment: @MikeBrant why its giving me _"Invalid xml response."_?

Comment: @MikeBrant How would i know what browseNode my search term belongs to? The api refuses to return results when trying to get 2nd page using the "SearchItem" method if no or "All" "SearchIndex" is provided?